# How to make camera Rotation smooth?

Tags: animation, camera

I got a problem when animate the camera. When it changes the angle, the turn is hard. How can I make it a smooth transition? Graph attached. Thanks!

[image]

There is a closer look of the rotation. I can not even add more frames to make it smooth.

I guess this video will explain more clear of this problem.

[Camera Rotation Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh0lQ.jpg)

There is the file.

[image]

Comment: hard to say what's the problem, you probably need to give it more time to make its rotation?

Comment: The rotation supposed be transferred in 20 frames. Location is find, but the rotation is like taking a sharp 90 degree left turn.

Comment: Thank you Robin, I watched the video, have not figure out how to fix this problem. it is confusing. lol

Comment: Robin, it does not look like a gimbal lock problem. I switched XYZ Euler, the result is the same.

Comment: File uploaded. :D

Comment: It's because the track to constraint.

Comment: One uploaded you need to share the link to us so we can access it.

Comment: @Leander is on it .. use Damped Track to Z axis, and explicitly key the roll (Z-rotation). [this sort of thing?](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/SRDOo2B0/)

Comment: @L0Lock the file is at the end of the original post.

Comment: @Robin Betts I am totally lost. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @BlenderNueva  .. as in the .blend I posted? Is that close?

Comment: @RobinBetts Just seen there is a file. Sorry. it is working. You Changed the Euler angle and Damp tracking instead of Track to. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: @BlenderNueva I adjusted a couple of Z rotation keys on the camera, to level the roll at the bottom position, and knocked out a couple of others, so it held. I guess others could go, to clean up. Rule of thumb for me, let the constraint do the work, then introduce a minimum number of keys, which don't fight what the constraint is doing. We're pointing with Z, so around Z is OK.